# How to add date in the form of DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss to the X-axis of a TimeSeries graph using jfreechart?

Tags: datetime, tooltip, time-series, jfreechart

I'm trying to make a graph showing the minimum and maximum CPU Utilization along with the time that the peaks occurred by a particular application for 30 days. The dates are easily obtained on the X-Axis, however, when I zoom in, all tooltips corresponding to the data points are given the time stamp of 12 AM of their corresponding date by default. How can I change this default time to the required time stamp?

Here's a screenshot for your reference:

[image]

Is there a way to add date AND time to the X-axis in the DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:SS format?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Kriti

Comment: Cross-posted [here](http://www.jfree.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=116971).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6770477/230513), The `StandardXYToolTipGenerator` uses `DateFormat.getInstance()` for dates, which is something like `MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss` in my `Locale`. Be sure you're adding values having the needed resolution, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15521956/230513) using `new Second()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the format by calling `setDateFormatOverride()` on the plot's axis.

In your case it would look something like this.

```
DateAxis axis = (DateAxis) plot.getDomainAxis();
axis.setDateFormatOverride(new SimpleDateFormat("DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:SS"));
```

See [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for see more time formats.