# JFreeChart: Add multiple series to DynamicTimeSeriesCollection and update them properly

Tags: java, jfreechart

I have a dynamic live graph made with JFreeChart. My question is : 
How to add multiple series to *DynamicTimeSeriesCollection* and update them properly, because I need 3 lines /*series*/ with different color in my plot. ? 

 

 
Here is my code:

```
    dataset = new DynamicTimeSeriesCollection(1, 200, new Second());
    dataset.setTimeBase(new Second(0, 0, 0, 23, 1, 2014));
    //Add series
    dataset.addSeries(new float[1], 0, "key1");
```

Everything is working fine until I add second series with different key:

```
 dataset.addSeries(new float[1], 0, "key2");
```

The problem is that my

```
dataset.advanceTime();
dataset.appendData(newData);
```

methods does not know to which series to refer because they take no parameter like series key, for example.

Comment: Possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15517509/230513).

Comment: This answered my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add series and use the second parameter as a key:

```
dataset.addSeries(new float[1], 0, "X");
dataset.addSeries(new float[1], 1, "Y");
dataset.addSeries(new float[1], 2, "Z");
```

Use the key set in the series as a place in the float array.

```
public void update(float valueX, float valueY , float valueZ) {
    float[] newData = new float[3];
    newData[0] = valueX;
    newData[1] = valueY;
    newData[2] = valueZ;
    dataset.advanceTime();
    dataset.appendData(newData);
}
```