# Weird Calendar error with JFreeChart

Tags: java, plot, jfreechart, timeserieschart

**I "solved" the problem by using a `TimeSeries` instead of a `DynamicTimeSeries` since I realized I don't need the latter when my only purpose is to update the graph manually. Also, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31902373/real-time-graph-plotting-starting-time) for further reference.**

I am trying to make a linechart from a list while also being able to make the graph auto-update whenever I add values to the graph. I use **`DynamicTimeSeriesCollection`** for that.
The elements of the list are the current prices at a specific second. The length of the list is therefore the length of the time interval (in seconds) I want to plot. Creating the graph also [works fine](http://s21.postimg.org/mgnfpjdfr/bitcoin.jpg).

I am creating the graph with

```
Chart bitcoinChart = new Chart("bitcoin", prices);
```

My Chart class is here:

```
import it.unimi.dsi.fastutil.doubles.DoubleArrayList;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.ValueAxis;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.XYPlot;
import org.jfree.data.time.DynamicTimeSeriesCollection;
import org.jfree.data.time.Second;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYDataset;
import org.jfree.ui.ApplicationFrame;
import org.jfree.ui.RefineryUtilities;
import java.awt.*;


public class Chart extends ApplicationFrame {

    private String title;
    private DynamicTimeSeriesCollection dataset;

    public Chart(final String title, DoubleArrayList doubleArrayList) {
        super(title);
        this.title = title;

        Second second = new Second(30, 41, 12, 12, 8, 2015);
        dataset = new DynamicTimeSeriesCollection(1, doubleArrayList.size(), second);
        dataset.setTimeBase(second);
        dataset.addSeries(doubleArrayListToFloatArray(doubleArrayList), 0, title);

        JFreeChart chart = createChart(dataset);
        this.add(new ChartPanel(chart), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        this.pack();
        RefineryUtilities.centerFrameOnScreen(this);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }



    public void update(Double data) {
            float[] newData = new float[1];
            newData[0] = data.floatValue();
            dataset.advanceTime();
            dataset.appendData(newData);

    }


    private JFreeChart createChart(final XYDataset dataset) {
        final JFreeChart result = ChartFactory.createTimeSeriesChart(
                title, "time", "price", dataset, true, true, false);

        final XYPlot plot = result.getXYPlot();
        ValueAxis domain = plot.getDomainAxis();
        domain.setAutoRange(true);
        ValueAxis range = plot.getRangeAxis();
        range.setAutoRange(true);
        return result;
    }


    public static float[] doubleArrayListToFloatArray(DoubleArrayList doubleArrayList) {
        float[] floatArray = new float[doubleArrayList.size()];
        for(int j=0; j<doubleArrayList.size(); j++) floatArray[j] = doubleArrayList.get(j).floatValue();
        return floatArray;
    }
}
```

A weird error seems to happen whenever I try to add a new value with

```
Double test = 260d;
bitcoinchart.update(test);
```

. The error is:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -530
at sun.util.calendar.BaseCalendar.getCalendarDateFromFixedDate(BaseCalendar.java:453)
at java.util.GregorianCalendar.computeFields(GregorianCalendar.java:2397)
at java.util.GregorianCalendar.computeTime(GregorianCalendar.java:2818)
at java.util.Calendar.updateTime(Calendar.java:3353)
at java.util.Calendar.getTimeInMillis(Calendar.java:1782)
at org.jfree.data.time.Second.getFirstMillisecond(Second.java:317)
at org.jfree.data.time.DynamicTimeSeriesCollection.getX(DynamicTimeSeriesCollection.java:906)
at org.jfree.data.time.DynamicTimeSeriesCollection.getX(DynamicTimeSeriesCollection.java:731)
at org.jfree.data.xy.AbstractXYDataset.getXValue(AbstractXYDataset.java:77)
at org.jfree.data.general.DatasetUtilities.iterateToFindDomainBounds(DatasetUtilities.java:1426)
at org.jfree.data.general.DatasetUtilities.findDomainBounds(DatasetUtilities.java:694)
at org.jfree.chart.renderer.xy.AbstractXYItemRenderer.findDomainBounds(AbstractXYItemRenderer.java:720)
at org.jfree.chart.renderer.xy.AbstractXYItemRenderer.findDomainBounds(AbstractXYItemRenderer.java:692)
at org.jfree.chart.plot.XYPlot.getDataRange(XYPlot.java:4462)
at org.jfree.chart.axis.DateAxis.autoAdjustRange(DateAxis.java:1293)
at org.jfree.chart.axis.DateAxis.configure(DateAxis.java:755)
at org.jfree.chart.plot.XYPlot.configureDomainAxes(XYPlot.java:974)
at org.jfree.chart.plot.XYPlot.datasetChanged(XYPlot.java:4539)
at org.jfree.data.general.AbstractDataset.notifyListeners(AbstractDataset.java:232)
at org.jfree.data.general.AbstractDataset.fireDatasetChanged(AbstractDataset.java:215)
at org.jfree.data.general.AbstractSeriesDataset.seriesChanged(AbstractSeriesDataset.java:114)
at org.jfree.data.time.DynamicTimeSeriesCollection.fireSeriesChanged(DynamicTimeSeriesCollection.java:844)
at org.jfree.data.time.DynamicTimeSeriesCollection.advanceTime(DynamicTimeSeriesCollection.java:595)
at com.wordnik.client.Chart.update(Chart.java:43)
at com.wordnik.client.AlgoTest.main(AlgoTest.java:60)
at com.wordnik.client.Main.main(Main.java:18)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
```

This error is caused by the **`dataset.advanceTime()`** line. Apparently the calendar is complaining whenever I try to step further another second, but I can't figure out why.

Comment: 1.) See this related [Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31902373/230513). 2.) See this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15521956/230513). Please edit your question to include a [complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that focuses on a single question.

Comment: 2.) See also this [alternate approach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11895709/230513).