# Dual JFreeChart not running; only one running

Tags: java, swing, jfreechart

Please let me know how I can make a program for `JFreeChart` in a `JFrame`. There are two `JFreeCharts` and both are visible, but only one is running; the other is still, why it is happening? Is there any sequential mistake in my code or what?

If you explain or give any hint, I shall be thankful to you.

Please read carefully and you can run on your laptop/PC, it is running code.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.ValueAxis;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.XYPlot;
import org.jfree.data.time.DynamicTimeSeriesCollection;
import org.jfree.data.time.Second;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYDataset;
import org.jfree.ui.ApplicationFrame;

/**
 * @see http://stackoverflow.com/a/15521956/230513
 * @see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5048852
 */
public class Grid_Layout extends ApplicationFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static final String TITLE1 = "X-Axis";
    private static final String TITLE2 = "Y-Axis";
    private static final String TITLE3 = "Z-Axis";
    private static final String START = "Start";
    private static final String STOP = "Stop";
    private static final float MINMAX = 100;
    private static final int COUNT = 2 * 60;
    private static final int FAST = 100;
    private static final int SLOW = FAST * 5;
    private static final Random random = new Random();
    private static final Random random2 = new Random();
    private Timer timer;
    private Timer timer2;

    public Grid_Layout(final String title) {
        super(title);
        
        final XYDataset dataset = createDataset1();
        JFreeChart chart = createChart(dataset);

        final XYDataset dataset2 = createDataset2();
        JFreeChart chart2 = createChart2(dataset2);
        

        final JButton run = new JButton(STOP);
        run.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String cmd = e.getActionCommand();
                if (STOP.equals(cmd)) {
                    timer.stop();
                    run.setText(START);
                } else {
                    timer.start();
                    run.setText(STOP);
                }
            }
        });

        final JComboBox<String> combo = new JComboBox<String>();
        combo.addItem("Fast");
        combo.addItem("Slow");
        combo.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if ("Fast".equals(combo.getSelectedItem())) {
                    timer.setDelay(FAST);
                } else {
                    timer.setDelay(SLOW);
                }
            }
        });

        this.add(new ChartPanel(chart) {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(640, 480);
            }
        }, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        this.add(new ChartPanel(chart2) {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(640, 480);
            }
        }, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JPanel btnPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        btnPanel.add(run);
        btnPanel.add(combo);
        this.add(btnPanel);
    }

    private float randomValue() {
        return (float) (random.nextGaussian() * MINMAX / 3);
    }

    private float[] gaussianData() {
        float[] a = new float[COUNT];
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            a[i] = randomValue();
        }
        return a;
    }

    private JFreeChart createChart(final XYDataset dataset) {
        final JFreeChart result = ChartFactory.createTimeSeriesChart(TITLE1, "Time (seconds)", "Intensity (cm/s)",
                dataset, true, true, false);

        final XYPlot plot = result.getXYPlot();
        ValueAxis domain = plot.getDomainAxis();
        domain.setAutoRange(true);

        ValueAxis range = plot.getRangeAxis();
        range.setRange(-MINMAX, MINMAX);
        range.setAutoRange(true);
        return result;
    }

    private JFreeChart createChart2(final XYDataset dataset) {
        final JFreeChart result = ChartFactory.createTimeSeriesChart(TITLE2, "Time (seconds)", "Intensity (cm/s)",
                dataset, true, true, false);

        final XYPlot plot = result.getXYPlot();
        ValueAxis domain = plot.getDomainAxis();
        domain.setAutoRange(true);

        ValueAxis range = plot.getRangeAxis();
        range.setRange(-MINMAX, MINMAX);
        range.setAutoRange(true);
        return result;
    }

    public void start() {
        timer.start();
    }

    private XYDataset createDataset1() {
        final DynamicTimeSeriesCollection dataset = new DynamicTimeSeriesCollection(1, COUNT, new Second());
        dataset.setTimeBase(new Second(0, 0, 0, 24, 5, 2022));
        dataset.addSeries(gaussianData(), 0, "X");
        timer = new Timer(FAST, new ActionListener() {
            float[] newData = new float[1];

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                newData[0] = randomValue();
                dataset.advanceTime();
                dataset.appendData(newData);
            }
        });
        return dataset;
    }

    private XYDataset createDataset2() {
        final DynamicTimeSeriesCollection dataset = new DynamicTimeSeriesCollection(1, COUNT, new Second());
        dataset.setTimeBase(new Second(0, 0, 0, 26, 5, 2022));
        dataset.addSeries(gaussianData(), 0, "Y");
        timer2 = new Timer(FAST, new ActionListener() {
            float[] newData2 = new float[1];

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                newData2[0] = randomValue();
                dataset.advanceTime();
                dataset.appendData(newData2);
            }
        });
        return dataset;
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Grid_Layout demo = new Grid_Layout("Vibration Analyser");
                demo.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 1));
                demo.pack();
                demo.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                demo.setVisible(true);
                demo.start();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I only see timer.start() in the posted code. Where do you have timer2.start()?

Comment: camickr,  thank youuuuuuu soooooooooooo much brother now it is running when I add timer2.start() in start function WOW awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5048863/230513), I've re-factored your variation to reflect several points about multiple instances of [jfreechart](/questions/tagged/jfreechart) in Swing.

- As noted by @camickr, you need to reference *both* `timer` and `timer2` in your handlers.
- Use [`GridLayout(0, 1)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/GridLayout.html) to allow adding multiple grids in a column, without the continual need to update as charts are added.
- Consider `GridChart`, a subclass of `ChartPanel`, shown below.
- Use named constants whenever possible.
- The example illustrates [migrating](https://github.com/jfree/jfreechart#migration-from-jfreechart-10x) to [jfreechart](/questions/tagged/jfreechart) v1.5.3, the current release.

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.ValueAxis;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.XYPlot;
import org.jfree.data.time.DynamicTimeSeriesCollection;
import org.jfree.data.time.Second;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYDataset;
import org.jfree.chart.ui.ApplicationFrame;

/**
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/72411813/230513
 * @see http://stackoverflow.com/a/15521956/230513
 * @see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5048852
 */
public final class Grid_Layout extends ApplicationFrame {

    private static final int CHART_WIDTH = 600;
    private static final int CHART_HEIGHT = 300;
    private static final String TITLE1 = "X-Axis";
    private static final String TITLE2 = "Y-Axis";
    private static final String TITLE3 = "Z-Axis";
    private static final String START = "Start";
    private static final String STOP = "Stop";
    private static final float MINMAX = 100;
    private static final int COUNT = 2 * 60;
    private static final int FAST = 100;
    private static final int SLOW = FAST * 5;
    private static final Random random = new Random();
    private Timer timer;
    private Timer timer2;

    private static class GridChart extends ChartPanel {

        public GridChart(JFreeChart chart) {
            super(chart);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(CHART_WIDTH, CHART_HEIGHT);
        }
    }

    public Grid_Layout(final String title) {
        super(title);

        final XYDataset dataset = createDataset1();
        JFreeChart chart = createChart(dataset);

        final XYDataset dataset2 = createDataset2();
        JFreeChart chart2 = createChart2(dataset2);

        final JButton run = new JButton(STOP);
        run.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String cmd = e.getActionCommand();
                if (STOP.equals(cmd)) {
                    timer.stop();
                    timer2.stop();
                    run.setText(START);
                } else {
                    timer.start();
                    timer2.start();
                    run.setText(STOP);
                }
            }
        });

        final JComboBox<String> combo = new JComboBox<String>();
        combo.addItem("Fast");
        combo.addItem("Slow");
        combo.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if ("Fast".equals(combo.getSelectedItem())) {
                    timer.setDelay(FAST);
                    timer2.setDelay(FAST);
                } else {
                    timer.setDelay(SLOW);
                    timer2.setDelay(SLOW);
                }
            }
        });

        JPanel gridPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
        gridPanel.add(new GridChart(chart));
        gridPanel.add(new GridChart(chart2));

        JPanel btnPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        btnPanel.add(run);
        btnPanel.add(combo);
        this.add(gridPanel);
        this.add(btnPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }

    private float randomValue() {
        return (float) (random.nextGaussian() * MINMAX / 3);
    }

    private float[] gaussianData() {
        float[] a = new float[COUNT];
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            a[i] = randomValue();
        }
        return a;
    }

    private JFreeChart createChart(final XYDataset dataset) {
        final JFreeChart result = ChartFactory.createTimeSeriesChart(TITLE1, "Time (seconds)", "Intensity (cm/s)",
            dataset, true, true, false);

        final XYPlot plot = result.getXYPlot();
        ValueAxis domain = plot.getDomainAxis();
        domain.setAutoRange(true);

        ValueAxis range = plot.getRangeAxis();
        range.setRange(-MINMAX, MINMAX);
        range.setAutoRange(true);
        return result;
    }

    private JFreeChart createChart2(final XYDataset dataset) {
        final JFreeChart result = ChartFactory.createTimeSeriesChart(TITLE2, "Time (seconds)", "Intensity (cm/s)",
            dataset, true, true, false);

        final XYPlot plot = result.getXYPlot();
        ValueAxis domain = plot.getDomainAxis();
        domain.setAutoRange(true);

        ValueAxis range = plot.getRangeAxis();
        range.setRange(-MINMAX, MINMAX);
        range.setAutoRange(true);
        return result;
    }

    public void start() {
        timer.start();
        timer2.start();
    }

    private XYDataset createDataset1() {
        final DynamicTimeSeriesCollection dataset = new DynamicTimeSeriesCollection(1, COUNT, new Second());
        dataset.setTimeBase(new Second(0, 0, 0, 24, 5, 2022));
        dataset.addSeries(gaussianData(), 0, "X");
        timer = new Timer(FAST, new ActionListener() {
            float[] newData = new float[1];

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                newData[0] = randomValue();
                dataset.advanceTime();
                dataset.appendData(newData);
            }
        });
        return dataset;
    }

    private XYDataset createDataset2() {
        final DynamicTimeSeriesCollection dataset = new DynamicTimeSeriesCollection(1, COUNT, new Second());
        dataset.setTimeBase(new Second(0, 0, 0, 26, 5, 2022));
        dataset.addSeries(gaussianData(), 0, "Y");
        timer2 = new Timer(FAST, new ActionListener() {
            float[] newData2 = new float[1];

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                newData2[0] = randomValue();
                dataset.advanceTime();
                dataset.appendData(newData2);
            }
        });
        return dataset;
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Grid_Layout demo = new Grid_Layout("Vibration Analyser");
                demo.pack();
                demo.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                demo.setVisible(true);
                demo.start();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Very Nice, thank you, I left many things during coding because I am learning it but you mentioned them it is great.